# text-overflow: ellipsis in mat-expansion-panel header

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

Using a mat-expansion-panel for displaying texts that can be collapsed. The only thing missing are the 3 dots that should be provided by the css text-overflow: ellipsis style. However this does not seem to work in the mat-expansion-panel-header as shown in the image below.

You can see my code here at stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4s7pfw?file=app/expansion-overview-example.html

[image: Want an ellipsis when expansion panel is collapsed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was working recently on the similar situation and solution/explanation is following:

For the first, this situation is the same with any situation where we need to have ellipsis, only difference is that containers in mat-expansion are `display: flex;`

To make ellipsis working generally we have 2 ways:

1. [Single line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779293/css-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)
2. Multiline solution with complicated
       tricks and using `:after` but I don't like these solutions and will focus on single line text with ellipsis

Solutions for Material Expansion panel:

1. `display: block;` for mat-panel-description, Existing topic:
   [Text overflow ellipsis dynamic width inside an angular material extension panel description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439658/text-overflow-ellipsis-dynamic-width-inside-an-angular-material-extension-panel)
2. Keep it `display: flex` and set `min-width: 0;` for mat-expansion-panel-header-title, I like this solution a lot.
   Existing topic: [Ellipsis in flexbox container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465745/ellipsis-in-flexbox-container)

So I forked your code and implemented my suggestion.
https://angular-4s7pfw-wrmxo1.stackblitz.io

Result:
[image]